# How to fit a Gaussian process with a latent variable and fixed feature weights?

Tags: gaussian-process, latent-variable

I have a model of observations $y_i \sim  a_i(x_iw) + \epsilon$ , where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, $x_i$ is $K>1$-dimensional input on trial $i$, $w$ are $K$ weights that don't change with $i$, and $a_i$ is a latent variable that smoothly changes with $i$, i.e. $A=[a_1,...a_N]\sim N(0,\Sigma_p)$. I want to find $A_{MAP}$ and $w_{MAP}$, but I am not sure how to do this.

My goal here is to find a frozen "profile" of weights $w$ which together with an autocorrelated scalar $a$ gives the best possible fit to $y_i$. I understand that $a_i$ and $w$ are identifiable up to a constant multiplier, but as far as I understand the shape of optimal $w$ is unique for well-behaved data, which is what matters to me.

If for example either $A$ or $w$ were known, we could use the standard equations from Rasmussen-Williams. For a fixed $w$ we'd have $\Phi_A=Xw$ and the posterior covariance for $A$ would be $\Sigma_{post,A}=(\sigma^{-2} \Phi_A\Phi_A^T+\Sigma_p)^{-1}$ and $A_{MAP}=\sigma^{-2}\Sigma_{post,A}^{-1}\Phi_A y$ . Similarly if the $a_i$ were known, $\Phi_w=A\circ X$ where every row $x_i$ is multiplied by a scalar $a_i$, and we'd have $\Sigma_{post,w}=(\sigma^{-2} \Phi_w^T\Phi_w+\Sigma)^{-1}$ and $w_{MAP}=\sigma^{-2}\Sigma_{post,w}^{-1}\Phi_w y$ where $\Sigma$ is e.g. a ridge covariance matrix, and the dimensions of $\Sigma_{post,w}$ are $K$x$K$ rather than $N$x$N$ .

With both $A$ and $w$ unknown, we need to find a posterior in form $p(A,w|Y)$, which requires square completion with respect to both $A$ and $w$, which I'm not sure is possible.

I'm not a statistician, but this seems to me like a problem that should have a standard solution. Something along the lines of "find an optimal fixed kernel, and a latent variable that together fit the data sufficiently well". Any constructive input is appreciated!